# How to display WEBP images with fallback to JPG images using react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, jpeg, react-bootstrap, webp, fallback

I am currently implementing a website using ReactJS and [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

I followed this [Image Component usage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-bootstrap-image-component/), which enables me to display images in my website.

Now that I want to optimize the website by changing my images from JPG to WEBP (I will do the offline conversion myself and place all the images of two different extensions in the same folder). After that, I would like to display WEBP images to those visitors who can process it, and fallback to JPG images for those who can't.

I did some research but found some techniques like [using `picture` tag](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/performance/embracing-modern-image-formats/) that is not what I am using in my website (I am using [react-bootstrap Image](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/images/)), or the use of Gatsby, which I am not familiar with.

The code I have now is something like this:

```
<Image src="my/local/path/image.jpg"/>
```

I just want to use fallback concept in this Image component. Is there any way to do it without complex customization? Additional third party library is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v2.7.0/src/Image.tsx) posted with bootstrap [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/images/), it seems that the `Image` component internally outputs `img` while passing props and assigning needed classes to it, so I think the following example should work.

I only tested it with `webp` disabled on Firefox, but here is a quick demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zf6que?file=src/App.js).

```
<picture>
  <source srcSet="imgurl/img.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <source srcSet="imgurl/img.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
  <Image src="imgurl/img.jpg" alt="image" fluid rounded />
</picture>
```

The output of the above in HTML should be similar to:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="imgurl/img.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <source srcset="imgurl/img.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
  <img src="imgurl/img.jpg" alt="image" class="img-fluid rounded" />
</picture>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to disable webp on Firefox so I can test the demo?

Comment: @holydragon Go to `about:config`, search for the config `image.webp.enabled` and temporarily disable it worked for me with Firefox.

Comment: Okay, I tried temporarily disable webp in Firefox and tested the demo. It does get the job done as intended. However, there is an error shown in the console about the webp file. Is there any way we can make it silent? i.e. not error.

Comment: @holydragon For me I did not get an error in the console, so not sure how it could be avoided. It seems that at this time `webp` is rather widely [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=webp) except for IE , so I think perhaps this error message would not happen very often, just as a reference.